# Where to specify SPL token name or address when transferring

Tags: transactions, spl-token, transfer, spl-token-program

Somebody from Discord was nice enough to point me to look at https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/modules.html#transfer but where do I specify what SPL token I want to transfer, let's say USDC.

And are `source` and `owner` the same which is the sender wallet?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Both the `Source` and the `Destination` should be the token's associated account. An associated token account *(ATA for short)* is specific to a single token, so that's how the `transfer()` method knows which token to transfer.

You get the source and destination ATAs with `getAssociatedTokenAddress()`: https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/modules.html#getAssociatedTokenAddress